# Carbon get current date if variable is null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon

Inside my blade edit form, I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="birth" class="form-control" id="birth" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($associado->birth)->format('d/m/Y') }}">
```

The problem is: if `$associado->birth` is NULL in database, Carbon is returning current date.

What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: Is `$associado` an Eloquent model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to check if the value is `null`.

Furthermore, you could add `birth` to the `$dates` array property in your eloquent model.

```
protected $dates = [
    'dates'
];
```

This will tell the eloquent model to cast this column to a `Carbon` instance like it does for `created_at` and `updated_at`. If the column if `null` it will simply return null.

Your code would then look something like:

```
{{ $associado->birth ? $associado->birth->format('d/m/Y')  : null }}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$associado->birth` is NULL before parsing it with Carbon.

If it has a true value, it is not NULL and you can parse it - otherwise just return set null in your value.

Here is an example using the ternary operator

```
value="{{ $associado->birth ? \Carbon\Carbon::parse($associado->birth)->format('d/m/Y') : null}}
```

Then again, when using this much logic, it should be put inside it's own function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `createFromFormat()` of `Carbon`.

```
value = "{{$associado->birth ? \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d\m\Y',
          $associado->birth)->toDateString() : null}}"
```

This will check string value of date stored in database and give empty in case of `Null` value.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since we expect a `parse` function to return specifically a Carbon (as parsing implies), it returns a Carbon instance. You can use `make` function instead, to be able to get null in case a null parameter.
As mentioned [in an issue](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/1917) in Carbon repo,

> ```
> Carbon::parse(null); // Carbon instance of now
> Carbon::parse('2019-06-15 12:34:54'); // Carbon instance
> Carbon::make(null); // null
> Carbon::make('2019-06-15 12:34:54'); // Carbon instance
> ```