# carbon get current date when variable null even with protected $dates Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon, laravel-5.6

I'm facing a problem with carbon in laravel 5.6.
when returning data from DB, if a timestamp field has null values, carbon is returning current date, even if i have `protected $dates`.

published_at in DB is null.

Model:

```
protected $dates = ['published_at'];
```

blade:

```
value="{{ old('published_at', $post->published_at)}}"
```

I already try the suggestion on [Carbon get current date if variable is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118001/carbon-get-current-date-if-variable-is-null) but Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your problem with help of [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). So, don't add `published_at` to `$dates` propery and just define this accessor:

```
public function getPublishedAtAttribute($published_at)
{
    return is_null($published_at) ? null : Carbon::parse($published_at);
}
```

Comment: thank you this is worked for me ... but ... why $published_at ? "" : "" didnt work?